# Is that possible to find the expression of $c$ in MVT for specific function?

Tags: analysis, functions, derivatives

If $f(x) $ is a differentiable function in the interval $[x_0,x_1]$

The MVT implies the equation $\frac{f(x_0)-f(x_1)}{x_0-x_1}=f'(c)$ where, $c\in[x_0 ,x_1]$.

Is that possible to find the exact expression of $c$ using $x_0$ and $x_1$
other than in the form $c=f'^{-1}(\frac{f(x_0)-f(x_1)}{x_0-x_1})$?

Let's make the case much simpler.

How to find the equation of a tangent to the function $f(x)=e^x$ which parallel

to the secant line through $(1,e)$ and $(m,e^m)$.

Comment: Umm... plug the values and function into your MVT equation and solve for $c$?

Comment: Well, it’s not always unique.

Comment: @Randall It is here, but even if it weren’t, the problem at hand asks for _any_ tangent line parallel to the secant.

Comment: A better phrase than "the intersection between $(1,e)$ and $(m,e^m)$ " would be "the secant line through..." those two points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f'$ is a bijection, we can take the inverse. For example,

$$\frac{e^m-1}{e-1}=e^c$$

$$c= \ln\left( \frac{e^m-1}{e-1}\right)$$

Comment: Is there any other expression? If I want to solve the equation $e^x-e=4(x-1)$. The other expression of $c$ will directly lead to the answer.

Comment: Ultimately the question is how easy is it to find an inverse, of which I don't think it is easy in general. For your question, you might want to check out Lambert W function.